# EGENERATE_IMAGE-2: Image size specified not large enough to draw image. (Bar size determined to be less than 1 pixel)

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode

I want to create barcode image using `BarcodeLib` but always i have the same issue not large enough to draw image.
this is my code:

```
    BarcodeLib.Barcode b = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
    string productid = item.ProductId;
    var img1 = b.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, productid, 290, 120);
```

I try to change the width and height but always same problem.

---

I'm using this NuGet:

[image: nuget]

Comment: Can you please clarify where this library is coming from specifically - is a NuGet package, or commercial product (might be outside SO scopes)  - what namespace are we in (your tag is [crystal-reports] so is it `BarcodeLib.Barcode.CrystalReports`?). In other words, if someone wanted to reproduce the issue you're having how would we recreate the context.

Comment: it is a NuGet package .using BarcodeLib;

Comment: Great! Which NuGet package and (name and version) is it? The one I'm seeing is authored by Brad Barnhill and is at 2.4.0 is that it?

Comment: name : BarcodeLib  version: 2.4.0

Comment: This seems to be your first post so I'll offer the standard new member orientation: "If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an acceptable answer. If it provides some value give it an upvote. If it needs clarification add a comment." See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be exactly what it says it is. If there is enough width in the target size that the barcode can render each bar at more than 1 px, then the call succeeds.

[image: success]

Otherwise, like when I deliberately set the size too small, you get the error just the way you describe:

```
private void onButtonMakeBarcode(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BarcodeLib.Barcode barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();
    string productid = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    // Works - there is enough width to draw barcode with bars > 1 pixel
    pictureBox.Image = barcode.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, productid);
    pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;

    MessageBox.Show("Continue...");

    // Fails - I have deliberately set a draw size that is too small to render the product ID.
    pictureBox.Image = barcode.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, productid, 10, 10);
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Just a thought - a QR code might be the way to go if you're encoding more data than a barcode can hold.